# The identity $x/y-y/x = (y+x)(y^{-1}-x^{-1}).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, rational-functions

Difference of perfect square asserts that the expression $y^2-x^2$ factorizes as $(y+x)(y-x)$. On the train home last night, I noticed a variant on this. Namely, that $x/y-y/x$ factorizes as $(y+x)(y^{-1}-x^{-1}).$ Explicitly:

> **Proposition.** Let $R$ denote a ring, and consider $x,y \in R$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are units. Then the following identity holds. $$\frac{x}{y}-\frac{y}{x} = (y+x)(y^{-1}-x^{-1})$$

For example, in the rational numbers, we have:

$$\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2}{3} = 5\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** Does this variant on "difference of perfect squares" have a name?
>
> **Q1.** Is it part of a larger family of identities that includes $y^2-x^2 = (y-x)(y+x)$, and other variants?
>
> **Q2.** Does it have any interesting uses or applications, e.g. in calculus?

If anyone can think of better tags, please retag.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the connection between $y^2 - x^2$ and $xy^{-1} - x^{-1}y$.

Comment: @Kaster, the connection is merely that $(y+x)(y-x)$ looks similar to $(y+x)(y^{−1}−x^{−1}).$ These identities aren't literally special cases of each other AFAIK. They may, however, belong to a larger class of identities.

Comment: Well, I guess it depends which way you wanna go. For example, let's say that more wider class of identities satisfy $(y+x)(y^\alpha - x^\alpha)$, so if you simply open up parens you get
$$
y^{\alpha+1} - yx^\alpha + xy^\alpha - x^{\alpha+1}.
$$
which is not very interesting at all. But you can make it prettier if you get rid of some terms. For example, if you want to remove pure $x$ and $y$ terms, you put $\alpha = -1$, so you get your second identity. To remove mixed terms, you put $\alpha = 1$. But probably there are other generalizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as far as I know, but notice that your identity is
$$ (x+y)\frac{x-y}{xy} = (xy)^{-1}(x+y)(x-y) = \frac{x^2-y^2}{xy} = \frac{x}{y}-\frac{y}{x}, $$
so I'm not sure I'd say that it's really distinct from difference-of-two-squares.

As far as generalisation goes, you've got the old
$$ x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dotsb+ xy^{n-2}+xy^{n-1}). $$